# How can I track REST API usage by 3rd party application?

Tags: api, reporting

I am running out of API calls. I want to know what apps or processes are using API calls. I am not writing an app, merely using apps from the App Store.

I can see how many API calls have been used, but I don't know what application is making them.

[image]

[This SF help page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003706&language=en_US) mentions the API Usage report which sounds great until you see that it can't track REST API calls.

From the article:

> NOTE: This report displays SOAP API usage, but REST API (including
>   Bulk API) calls are not included in the report, which might explain
>   why the data displayed in the report does not match the figure
>   returned by the System Overview page.

Not super helpful because I don't know what protocol the different apps are using, and I still don't know what apps are using my API calls.

How can I figure out what apps and processes are using all my API requests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Track number of API calls for an application](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64557/track-number-of-api-calls-for-an-application)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna very different questions I feel. That question is from someone working on an application. I am not working on an app, just using applications from the App Store etc. I might not have access to the API methods the other question is using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ["Event Log"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) to dig into details .

You can use [workbench tool](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) to dig deeper into these event logs with types as SOAP and REST API .

More info here

http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2014/11/event-log-file-field-lexicon.html?m=1

Comment: isn't eventLog an extra cost feature?

Comment: I am not sure on cost but you can get it enabled by support. An year back we used to reach SFDC but I am not sure now .